# NGINX in Docker caching IP addresses and delivering wrong Content-Type

Tags: docker, nginx, dns, webserver, openshift

**Summary:**
I want to make NGINX (not NGINX Plus) re-resolve the IP address from the DNS name by using a variable in `proxy_pass` (as suggested in [this official Nginx article in the section "Setting the Domain Name in a Variable"](https://www.nginx.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-nginx-plus/)). But when I do that it won't set/forward the correct `Content-Type` header, but always use `text/html`, for `.css`, `.js` etc. files.

**My setup:**
I have a frontend and a backend service running in separate Docker containers (to be deployed to OpenShift in production). There's also a third container that runs `nginx:latest` (v1.19.9 as of today) and acts as a reverse proxy, forwarding calls made to `/my-app` to the frontend and `/my-app/api` to the backend container. The NGINX reverse proxy has set them up as upstream servers using their DNS names.
All three containers run within the same custom Docker network, so resolving in itself works fine - but only, when NGINX is (re-)started.

**The problem:**
When the frontend or backend container gets restarted it may get a new IP address. Since NGINX caches IP addresses I'm getting a `502` when I make calls to them. I want NGINX to re-resolve the IP address more frequently, like NGINX Plus does. This is how the problem with the `Content-Type` came up, when I tried to have NGINX re-resolve DNS names.

**The configuration:**
Here's my NGINX configuration (simplified to the relevant stuff only):

```
  index    index.html index.htm;

  upstream upstream_frontend {
    server frontend:8080;
  }

  upstream upstream_backend {
    server backend:8000;
  }

  server {
    listen       8080;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    try_files    $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    
    rewrite ^/my-app$ $scheme://$http_host/my-app/ permanent;

    location /my-app {
      resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=1s;

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      proxy_pass_header Content-Type;

#     Attempt #1, NOT working: using a variable and an upstream server setup
      set $frontend_var "http://upstream_frontend/";
      proxy_pass http://$frontend_var;

#     Attempt #2, NOT working: using a variable and directly using the container name
#      set $frontend_var "http://frontend:8080/";
#      proxy_pass $frontend_var;

#     Attempt #3, working fine:  using NO variable and an upstream server setup, , but no DNS re-resolving happening :-(
#      proxy_pass http://upstream_frontend/;

#     Attempt #4, working fine:  using NO variable and directly using the container name, but no DNS re-resolving happening :-(
#      proxy_pass http://frontend:8080/;
    }

    location /my-app/api {
      resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=1s;

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

#     Attempt #1, NOT working: using a variable and an upstream server setup
      set $backend_var "http://upstream_backend/api";
      proxy_pass http://$backend_var;

#     Attempt #2, NOT working:  using a variable and directly using the container name
#      set $backend_var "http://backend:8000/api";
#      proxy_pass http://$backend_var;

#     Attempt #3, working fine:  using NO variable and an upstream server setup, , but no DNS re-resolving happening :-(
#      proxy_pass http://upstream_backend/api;

#     Attempt #4, working fine:  using NO variable and directly using the container name, but no DNS re-resolving happening :-(
#      proxy_pass http://backend:8000/api;
    }
  }
```

(Please note the `location /my-app {...}` and the `/` at the end of the `proxy_pass`, as the frontend is served from `/my-app`, whereas the frontend container itself, also served from NGINX, is operating directly on `...:8080/`, without the `/my-app` context path. And we have the same setup for the backend container that is listening on `:8000`, but when calls are forwarded to it we're removing the `/my-app` from them so they reach the container directly at `...:8000/api`.)

NGINX is running on port `9000` and when I open http://localhost:9000/my-app using the above *Attempt #1* or *Attempt #2* the `.css`, `.js`, image files etc. are all served with `Content-Type: text/html`, which prevents the browser from properly rendering the page, and shows messages like this in the debugger pane:

```
The stylesheet http://localhost:9000/my-app/static/css/main.df1d2133.chunk.css  was not loaded because its MIME type, ”text/html“ is not ”text/css"
```

At first I thought `proxy_pass_header Content-Type;` would fix this, but that doesn't help either.

And then I also learned from [this NGINX bug ticket](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1370) that *"When using variables in proxy_pass, if URI is specified, it is passed to the server as is, replacing the original request URI."*. This seems to be a possible cause for the `Content-Type` issue I have here.

Also, as you can see in the configuration I have set the Docker DNS IP: `resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=1s;`. I have also tried setting it outside the `location` block, that also didn't help.

**Question:**
So how do I have DNS re-resolving in NGINX (Open-Source) **with** the proper `Content-Type` still set? I don't **have** to use upstream servers, so I can get rid of them, should that be part of a possible fix.

**P.S.:**
I can't, as suggested in other StackOverflow comments, add separate `location` blocks to "retroactively" fix the `Content-Type` depending on folder, file name etc., because this is an evolving project and I worry it would require me to keep adding such hotfixes to the NGINX configuration on a regular basis.

**EDIT:**
The configuration I posted is included by NGINX's Docker container's configuration file which is this one, in case you were wondering about a few "missing" settings:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # This line includes my configuration above
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with `Content-Type`. You are using `proxy_pass` incorrectly. As you have already noted:

> When using variables in proxy_pass, if URI is specified, it is passed to the server as is, replacing the original request URI.

You currently have the following working configuration, but you want to replace it with a variable to force DNS resolution:

```
location /my-app {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:8080/;
}
```

The simplest solution is to use `rewrite...break` to make the changes to the URI, and remove the trailing `/` from the variable.

For example:

```
location /my-app {
    rewrite ^/my-app/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
    set $frontend_var "frontend:8080";
    proxy_pass http://$frontend_var;
}
```

---

Alternatively, capture the remainder of the original request using a *regular expression* `location`.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/my-app/?(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:8080/$1;
}
```

Comment: I tried both suggestions, unfortunately they show an error:  
`2021/05/24 15:08:21 [warn] 23#23: *1 using uninitialized "frontend_var" variable, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /my-app/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:9000"
2021/05/24 15:08:21 [error] 23#23: *1 no host in upstream "/", client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /myapp/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:9000"`

Comment: And the second suggestion (using a regexp) shows: `2021/05/24 15:11:48 [error] 23#23: *1 invalid port in upstream "http://upstream_frontend/", client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /my-app/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:9000"`

Comment: Unfortunately, there were too many `http://` strings - fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much, Richard! This worked! I ended up using the second suggestion, as the first one kept showing the `using uninitialized "frontend_var" variable` error message. I will post my final configuration as an answer here. Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 1):

So here's my final working setup. Thanks again, [@richard-smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith)!

Please note that...:

- I'm not using the `upstream` block as I'm deploying this to OpenShift. There's the concept of "Services" that fronts Pods (~= servers or containers), which is basically what `upstream` does in Nginx,
- I've re-ordered the `location` blocks so the more specific one, `/my-app/api`, gets hit first, as otherwise things will fail,
- I had to add the `$isargs$args` part as otherwise the URLs are not constructed properly and will fail, specifically for calls to my backend,
- and for OpenShift I had to add `.<PROJECT>.svc.cluster.local` on the `proxy_pass`, as otherwise the resolver will not be able to resolve the service.

This is the relevant setup, for the remaining (default) Nginx configuration see the configuration I posted in the EDIT of my initial question above.

```
index    index.html index.htm;

server {
  listen       8080;
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

  try_files    $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    
  rewrite ^/my-app$ $scheme://$http_host/my-app/ permanent;

  # Backend
  location ~ ^/my-app/api/?(.*)$ {
    # Use this for Docker...
    # resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=1s;
    # ... or use this for OpenShift
    # resolver dns-default.openshift-dns.svc.cluster.local ipv6=on valid=1s;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass_header Content-Type;

    proxy_pass http://backend.<PROJECT>.svc.cluster.local:8000/api/$1$is_args$args;
  }

  # Frontend
  location ~ ^/my-app/?(.*)$ {
    # Use this for Docker...
    # resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=1s;
    # ... or use this for OpenShift
    # resolver dns-default.openshift-dns.svc.cluster.local ipv6=on valid=1s;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass_header Content-Type;

    proxy_pass http://frontend.<PROJECT>.svc.cluster.local:8080/$1$is_args$args;
  }
}
```