# Using Variables With Nginx proxy_pass Directive

Tags: nginx, dns, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm trying to use variables with the Nginx proxy_pass directive to allow delayed DNS resolution, however, the following two configurations produce different results:

```
location /location1/ {
  proxy_pass https://location.domain.com:8000/;
}

location /location2/ {
  resolver 127.0.0.1 timeout=30s;
  set $location location.domain.com;
  proxy_pass https://$location:8000/;
}
```

The first location works as expected, while the second location results in just a blank white page.   Does using variables with the proxy_pass directive introduce some headers or any other changes that might be breaking the second location?  Or does the variable contain leading or trailing slashes or any other information other than an IP address?  Looking at the above configuration one would expect both locations to work identically.

Comment: You need a resolver when you use variables in the upstream domain name, but you already have one in your configuration. Are you sure your local DNS can resolve that domain? Try to execute `nslookup location.domain.com 127.0.0.1` (or any other command, e.g. `dig` if you don't have `nslookup` installed). Anything helpful in the nginx error log?

Comment: They will not work the same. When using variables in proxy_pass, if URI is specified, it is passed to the server as is, replacing the original request URI. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67673886/nginx-in-docker-caching-ip-addresses-and-delivering-wrong-content-type/67674433#67674433).